# Finding a room through it's name

Tags: screeps

Let us suppose i save in memory the name of a room - "1-1". How would i go around to access that room object without having access to any creep/structure in that room? Something like:

```
function(roomName){
  var room = Game.rooms.roomName; //what would the simplest and quickest code be?
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't access a room if you have no objects inside it. It is like the fog of war. In order to see what is inside a 
room (in other words, to get access to the room object instance) you have to send some of your creeps there.

**UPDATE**: [`Game.rooms`](http://screeps.com/docs/Game.php#rooms) property has been added to the API.

Comment: That makes sense, but still doesn't answer my question. What is the simplest way to get the room object from its name? I'm thinking that looping through all my creeps and comparing room names to be an overly exagerated step, trying to save on that cpu.

Comment: We may add some helper method for that in the future I think.

Comment: I agree. I would also like something like Game.rooms that contains the rooms that I can see.